# How to create a 3d array in c++ with each layer having its own data type

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created a 3d array with the int data type. But my needs are now more robust, where each layer of the array can be a different data type. FOr eg: layer1 can be of type int and layer 2 of type float. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's totally unclear what "layer" means to you.

Comment: add your current declaration and what you would *like*...

Comment: Create a data encapsulation class with the various data types, and some type identifier, with getter/setters then make an array of those.  If you want to be sloppy and lazy, jsut use a struct/union.

Comment: I think by "layer" he means dimension or axis.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like your data structure has reached a point of complexity where it would be better to represent it with a properly encapsulated class or even multiple nested classes instead of a multi-dimensional array. The methods of these classes depend on your actual requirements which can only be guessed from your post.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a 2D array of tuples. Let's say you want three layers which are `int`, `float`, and `char`. Then you'll want:

```
std::tuple<int, float, char> arr[X][Y];
```

Then the first two indices will give you the position in a "layer" the last is which layer:

```
std::get<2>(arr[5][7])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a simple way just define one structure which meets your requirements.